# Convert Range to List of Strings

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to generate the result given by

```
List = {"0", "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(\[Pi]\), \(\[Tau]\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(2  \[Pi]\), \(\[Tau]\)]\)", 
  "\!\(\*FractionBox[\(3  \[Pi]\), \(\[Tau]\)]\)"}
```

but with help of Range command.

How can I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: How about `Range[0, 3] Pi/tau`? Btw, don't use `List` as variable! It's a used symbol in Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you, but I need list of strings, where Pi and tau are fixed characters, but not variables.
Any alternative?

Comment: `ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ (Pi Range[0, 3]/\[Tau])`?

Comment: This is not I want, because the result depends on value of Tau. I need string with Tau literally without substitution. For example if I set:
    Tau = 1; the result will be different from the desired one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too pretty, but handles non-integer steps:

```
If[#==0,ToString[0],("\!\(\*FractionBox[\("<>If[Numerator@#===1,"", 
ToString[Numerator@#]]<>"  \[Pi]\), \("<>If[Denominator@#===1,"", 
ToString[Denominator@#]]<>"\[Tau]\)]\)")]&/@Range[0,3,1/2]
```

[image]

Comment: Hm.... I will try it. But is there a shorter and more simple way to do it?

Comment: This statement produces the result I want. Is there a way to simplify this piece of code? Thank you!

Comment: @AndreyKazak: If your range is only integer values * pi/tau, just remove all the *If* stuff and keep the first *ToString*. Other than that, no really simpler ways come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you need strings, then you can just create the symbolic list first and transform every entry into a string afterwards:

```
ToString[#, TraditionalForm] & /@ (Range[0, 3] Pi/τ)
```

If you have assigned a global value to `tau` and you can, as Marius already pointed out, use `Block` to localize the variable

```
τ = 4;
Block[{τ},
  ToString[#, TraditionalForm] & /@ (Range[0, 3] Pi/τ)
]
```

Comment: This is not I want, because the result depends on value of Tau. I need string with Tau literally without substitution.

Comment: Put it in a Block where you localize \[Tau], then the global value does not matter.

Comment: Didn't get your point. Can you provide an example please?

Comment: `Block[{\[Tau]}, 
 ToString[#, TraditionalForm] & /@ (Range[0, 3] Pi/\[Tau])]`